# Get java script variable in HTML

Tags: javascript

I want to get variable value in hidden HTML field. My code like:

```
<script lang=”text/javascript”>
   Var counter;
   Loop{
     Some Code . . . . 
     Counter++;
   }//end loop
</script>

<html>
   <body>
      // some code 
      <input type “hidden” name=”total” id=”total” value=”here I want to get Counter”>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### 1.) Get the DOM object of the element

```
var elem = document.getElementById("total");
```

#### 2.) Set the value

```
elem.value = your_variable;
```

Example:

```
var Counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("total"),
while(condition == true) {
    // some code
    Counter++;
    elem.value = Counter;
}
```

Comment: not geting value.I want to get counter value in HTML, my JS is in the head field where counter counts the dynamically add/remove the textfields. At the end I want the exact figure of counter variable. That counter's value I want to store in the hidden field, further I can post this value to PHP.(whole story)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of form field by Javascript DOM API.

```
<script lang=”text/javascript”>
var total = document.getElementById("total").value;

Var counter;
Loop{
Some Code . . . . 
Counter++;
}//end loop
```